# Passing a model through a view to another action without editing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a form that takes in a lot of data. All the data is stored in a model object.

When the form is submitted, if it passes validation, the model is passed to a confirmation view, which simply displays all of the information that was submitted in the form.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientProfile(ClientProfileFormModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("ClientProfileConfirmation",model);
            }

        return View(model);
    }
```

When the user clicks a submit button at the bottom, I need the model to come into an action so I can send an email.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientProfileConfirmationSubmit(ClientProfileFormModel model)
    {

        string emailToAdminBody = GenerateFirmProfileAdminEmail(model);
        EmailLogic.Instance.SendEmail("test@test.com", "test@test.com", "Firm profile from " + model.FirmAddress.Name, emailToAdminBody);

        return View(model);
    }
```

My problem is: I need a simple way of getting my model from the HttpPost action of the form (which sends you to the confirmation page after validation) to the HttpPost action of the confirmation. I would like to avoid filling the confirmation view with hidden inputs so that I can bring it all in via the form.

I've also tried storing the model in Session AND TempData, but both ways are returning null for some reason. I think it's to do with going through multiple actions.

This really shouldn't be that difficult! What am I missing? Is the only way to put in a bunch of hidden input fields into the form of the confirmation page?

Comment: Why not have one POST action that validates the model then uses the email service directly? Then return `RedirectToAction` to a GET action to confirm the email was sent.

Comment: Could you please show me the views? I need to check if you are posting the data correctly in the second form.

Comment: not sure why putting it in session is not working for you. i think there's a `Controller.Session` and a `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[]`.  try putting it in `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[]` instead of just 'Session[]`

Comment: @Jasen, that's the easy way to do this. But my intention is show a "summary" view of what they are about to submit, before the email is sent.

Comment: @JamieD77 I've tried both ways, and I've tried setting the session/tempdata variable in the view as well as the controller. No dice. I'm really confused as to what this could be. Seems like Sessions just don't work at all. I've tried several solutions including removing and adding the session module in the Web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I've used TempData and it's working fine.

The model:

```
public class ClientProfileFormModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    // GET
    public ActionResult ClientProfile()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientProfile(ClientProfileFormModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ClientProfileConfirmation", model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    // GET
    public ActionResult ClientProfileConfirmation(ClientProfileFormModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientProfileConfirmation()
    {
        var model = (ClientProfileFormModel) TempData["clientProfile"];
        string emailToAdminBody = GenerateFirmProfileAdminEmail(model);
        EmailLogic.Instance.SendEmail(...);

        TempData["success-message"] = "Your profile has been approved. Check your inbox.";
        return View("ClientProfileConfirmation", model);
    }
}
```

The ClientProfile View

```
@model StackOverflow.Models._31465719.ClientProfileFormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ClientProfile";
}

<h2>ClientProfile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClientProfileFormModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The ClientProfile Confirmation View:

```
@model StackOverflow.Models._31465719.ClientProfileFormModel

@{
    TempData["clientProfile"] = Model;
    ViewBag.Title = "ClientProfileConfirmation";
    var successMessage = TempData["success-message"];
}

<h2>ClientProfileConfirmation</h2>

@if (successMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p class="text-success">@successMessage</p>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <h4>ClientProfileFormModel</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

All I did in the last confirmation view was to save the model in the TempData:

```
TempData["clientProfile"] = Model;
```

And then read it in the controller:

```
var model = (ClientProfileFormModel) TempData["clientProfile"];
```

Comment: Your RedirectToAction("ClientProfileConfirmation", model); makes the model null, which is why I used return View(...).

Still absolutely no luck getting TempData or Session to work. I've tried pretty much every solution on StackOverflow.. I'm stumped as to what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, but you must be doing something wrong. I've created a test project with this exactly code (except the email stuff) and it is working. Could you show the code for your clientProfileFormModel?

Comment: You definitely weren't wrong. The issue was Sessions weren't enabled in my web.config. Upvoted for a perfectly valid solution. Thanks.